# Symfony UploadedFile not getting uploaded

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, is-uploaded-file

I am trying to create a UploadedFile from an existing file.But it is not getting uploaded successfully,neither it shows any error.

Here is my code

```
   $encoded_data = "This is a huge string";
   $filename = "tempFile";
   $handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename, "a+")
   file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename, $encoded_data);
   $file = new UploadedFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename, $filename, null, filesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename));
   var_dump($file->getClientSize());
   var_dump($file->getError());
   var_dump($file->isValid());
   var_dump(is_uploaded_file($file));
```

The result is

```
int 21
int 0
boolean false
boolean false
```

I am sure the tempFile exists at the document root!

Comment: can you also paste the content of your html file?

Comment: @NishchalGautam There is no html file.Please see the updated code.

Comment: How are you uploading a file if there is no html at all? how are you submitting a file to the server in the first place? If you're trying to write into a file, you could just use ```file_put_contents('filename','data');```

Comment: But I want an UploadedFile object of the file.
So I am trying to create an UploadableFile object manually.

Answer (score 1):

`is_uploaded_file()` will check that the file has actually been uploaded, so it will not work with your code, since the file *has not* been uploaded. That is why `isValid()` also returns false, as it is using `is_file_uploaded()` to check the file.
Once this said, UploadedFile does have a $test parameter which if set to true, will make `isValid()` not check if the file is actually uploaded. This is used for testing, where no files are actually uploaded. You could set this parameter to true and then `isValid()` would return true for your file. It is a hack, but maybe is what you need